# fire custom Event on click of a link in webview

Tags: javascript, titanium

Hi I am working in Titanium. I am facing an issue as under.
In picture I have a webview In which a link "(Learn More)" is present. And this text is coming from the website through JSON parsing I want to fire a custom event and not the actual url of the link (Learn More). I have searched a lot but unfortunately couldn't get the solution. Any help please ?
Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `preventDefault`:

```
$elem.on('click', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  doStuff();
})
```

Comment: you get your element, you get your event instance, you try `preventDefault`, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault